# Inject SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS into db_select()?

Tags: database

I've recently learned that [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5060385/151841) can give the number of rows in a table from almost any `SELECT` statement. It's raw SQL syntax is `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS field1, field2, ... FROM ...`

Is there an existing way I can that inject that syntax into `db_select()`?

I want to use this for creating a pager, so I'm already selecting some rows in the first place. It would be handy to get a count out of the query I'm already running. Doing a separate count query would be extra work in my case.

Comment: Are you sure your code need to use `db_select()`? In most of the cases you can use `db_query()` which is even faster.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Oh sheesh, of course I could. If you put that as an answer, I will accept it : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As made evident in [Compare db_query() and db_select() performance](https://www.drupal.org/node/1067802), `db_query()` is faster than `db_select()`, which should then be used when you need to make the query you are executing alterable from other module via [`hook_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7.x), for example when you need to get a list of nodes for which a user has access.

If that is not your case, then you can use `db_query()` and using the query you are showing is quite straight as `db_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS field1, field2 FROM ...")`.

Comment: Plus there isn't any support for `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in the default `SelectQuery` class so it would need some work and perhaps even an awkward workaround to get it working with `db_select`

Comment: Right, I would rather not implement a new class just to be able to add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` before the list of fields to query. But the bigger problem would probably be how to make Drupal use it without me explicitly using my class.